# Anlysis of circuit as excersice

Tags: circuit-design

I am trying to analyse this circuit as part of learning electronics. So far I think that this is just an DAC that goes to a non inverting opamp after the signal gets attenuated, it goes through a comparator, which decides if the signal of the sensor passes through or the DAC output you decided on.

To start is this right?
Secondly what is the use of R56 and R62?

Will this circuit work?

[image: sensor circuit]

Comment: Have you tried to simulate the circuit?

Comment: It's a DAC and not an ADC

Comment: You are right! Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s a two-channel threshold comparator for inputs ‘OUTA’ and ‘OUTB’ vs. ‘SENSOR’.

Each channel has AD822 op-amp (not ADC) with a gain of +5, the output of which is compared to a level ‘SENSOR’ by the channel’s LM139 comparator. The comparator output will be +5V high (not pulled down) when its corresponding channel is higher than the ‘SENSOR’ reference, otherwise it will be low.

Each LM139 won’t pass the ‘SENSOR’ voltage per se; only its comparison against the corresponding input voltage.

The input resistors (R56/R62, R61/R55) are meant to make an equal input bias current to the op-amp to reduce error. They don’t affect gain.

As to what this circuit is doing, hard to say without more details. If the IC at left is a DAC, then then the DAC would be setting the comparator thresholds for ‘SENSOR’.

Speculating further, the INTA and INTB are fed to a microcontroller, which could, together with the DAC settings, be implementing something like windowing limits, a hysteresis function, or means to measure the ‘SENSOR’ voltage without an ADC using software.